# Error with the sprintf() function in wpdb class

Tags: php, printf, wordpress

When i try to run my PHP application, i get an error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function __() in J:\sambit\UniServer\www\bbplan_console\inc\wp-db.php on line 1499

the code in line 1499 is:

```
function select( $db, $dbh = null ) {
   if ( is_null($dbh) )
      $dbh = $this->dbh;

   if ( !@mysql_select_db( $db, $dbh ) ) {
      $this->ready = false;
      //wp_load_translations_early();

      // Line 1499 follows:
      $this->bail( sprintf( __( '<h1>Can&#8217;t select
```

`sprintf()` is a function. I don't know why this is showing an error as this is the function of the wp-db class itself. I haven't created this.

Comment: The error isn't about `sprintf()` not existing, it is about the  string internationalization function `__()` not existing.  Not familiar enough with WP though to tell you how to include the right file.

Comment: See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2

Comment: thanks guys...a small problem..had to include the correct path for config.php :)